# how to read values from imagedata of a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, alpha-transparency

if i do a :

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(100,200,50,0.5)';  
ctx.fillRect(0,0,1,1);
```

and then a :

```
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,1,1);
console.log(imageData.data;
```

i get :

```
>>[50,100,25,254]
```

My question is : why 254 for alpha ?
I experiment that any values of alpha in fillStyle but 0 and 1 lead to 254
and a value of 0 or 1 lead to a log of 255 !

Comment: Do you know that you missed a `)` after the log?

Comment: @Bálint oh that's right !

Comment: You must have some existing pixels that you are rendering over. For a clear canvas filling the colour you show will produce a pixel with [100,201,50,127]

Comment: @Blindman67, sorry , i does not understand whay you mean

Comment: The code in you question should output to the console [100,201,50,127] if the canvas is clear and 2d context state is default

Comment: i do clear the canvas before, with `fillStyle = rgba(0,0,0,1)  fillRect(0,0,w,h)`

Comment: @Blindman67, actually the pixel produced will vary on every browser and every devices. This is the canvas fingerPrinting issue.

Comment: @Kaiido a variation of 127 for the alpha value is not a cross browser issues, such a discrepancy would make the canvas unusable. But the OP has cleared the problem up.,

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique technically what you do is not clearing the canvas. A clear canvas has no visible pixels, all bytes in a cleared canvas are 0. To clear the canvas use `clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)`

Comment: @Blindman67 : OMG ! IT WORKS FINE!   i did a pixel of rgba=(10,200,50,0.5) and i read a (5,100,25,127) !  ClearRect is a very important thing !!!!!

Comment: @Blindman67, I was referring to your comment where you ve got a 1/255 variation on the green channel and 2/255 on the alpha one. You said that OP should get that value. That's not true and misleading for future readers. He should get something around 100,200,50,125.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fill an area transparently, you don't actually fill it with the color you use, but you blend it with the background color instead. The 254 is probably just a vedy slight rounding error.